# refresh views with factories in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to update two views in my angular app which both have their own controllers.

I have a Factory:

```
angular.module('starter')
.factory('userFactory', function(DSCacheFactory){
    var user = DSCacheFactory.get("userData").get("user");
    if(user === undefined){

            return false

    }else{
        var name, email

            return {    
                        name:user.name,
                        email: user.userName
                    }
}
});
```

so when the user isn't logged in, the value is false. But when the user is logged in their username and name are displayed. The problem I'm having is that when I refresh the page the views are updated and I can see that the user is logged in, however I do not want to refresh the page, I want both views on the different controllers to update instantly.

Any push in the right direction? If you need me to elaborate on anything, please just ask

Thank you

Comment: You will need to update the user once the user is logged in. Can you show your login code and `DSCacheFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a $watch. Maybe you should reorganize your code so you don't need watchs. This makes

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['userFactory', function(userFactory) {

  $scope.$watch(
    function( $scope ) { return userFactory },
    function( user) {
        if (!user) console.log('login please');
        else console.log(user);
    }
  );
```

}]);

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea. You can use "appmodel" service share data at multiple controller.

controllers:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('ACtrl', ['$scope', 'appmodel', 'loginservice', function($scope, appmodel, loginservice) {
  $scope.User = appmodel.User;
  $scope.login = loginservice.login;
}])
.controller('BCtrl', ['$scope', 'appmodel', function($scope, appmodel) {
  $scope.User = appmodel.User;
}])
```

appmodel:

```
myApp.service('appmodel', [function(){
    var self = this;

  self.User = {};
  self.User.name = '';

}]);
```

login action:

```
myApp.service('loginservice', ['appmodel', 'userFactory', function(appmodel, userFactory){
    var self = this;

  self.login = function() {
    var user = userFactory;

    if (user !== false)
    {
      appmodel.User.name = user.name;
      appmodel.User.email = user.email;
    }
  }
}]);
```

More detail: [Full Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kvYOlWtW1RLdMTpH87tb?p=preview)